# Algorithm for creating a data structure based on a table

Tags: c#, algorithm, csv, kotlin

Given that I have the following table:

| Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Option A | Option AA | Option AAA |
| Option A | Option AB | Option ABA |
| Option A | Option AC | Option ACA |
| Option A | Option AD | Option ADA |
| Option A | Option AE | Option AEA |
| Option B | Option BA | Option BAA |
| Etc. | Etc. | Etc. |

Where each column represents a question. The first column is the initial question (lot of duplicate options), the last column is the final question (no duplicate options). If the first question gets answered, the answer decides which options the second question will show. So for example:

- First question is answered with: Option A
- Second question shows the following options:

  - AA, AB, AC, AD, AE

And I have the following data structure:

```kotlin
data class MultipleChoiceQuestion(
    val title: String,
    val options: List<Answer>,
    var givenAnswer: Answer? = null)

data class Answer(
   val title: String,
   val nextQuestion: MultipleChoiceQuestion? = null)
```

How could I morph this table into my data structure, or should I use a completely different structure. I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem and would appreciate it if someone could explain their thought process.

I have tried multiple implementations, mostly using recursion but I cant seem to figure out how to be able to implement the relationships between the different objects.

I do not need exact code examples, I'm just stuck on how to approach this in a somewhat efficient manner.

Comment: Is your question about reading the data from a .csv file, or about grouping it afterwards?

Comment: Grouping it afterwards, the csv format doesn't matter. I'll rephrase my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map that maps the chosen answers to the next set of answers and then let each question create the next question based upon the chosen answer. like this:

```kotlin
data class MultipleChoiceQuestion(
    val title: String,
    val options: List<Answer>,
    val chosenAnswer: Answer? = null
) {
    fun createNextQuestion(nextTitle: String): MultipleChoiceQuestion? {
        if (chosenAnswer != null) {
            return MultipleChoiceQuestion(
                title = nextTitle,
                options = answerMap[chosenAnswer]!!
            )
        } else return null
    }
}

data class Answer(val name: String)

val answerMap = mapOf(
    Answer("A") to listOf(Answer("AA"), Answer("AB"), Answer("AC"), Answer("AD"), Answer("AE")),
    Answer("B") to listOf(Answer("BA")),
    Answer("AA") to listOf(Answer("AAA")),
    .
    .
    .
)
```

Comment: https://uat-web.selfcare4me.com/dashboard/games/challenge